# How to solve 'Error while creating indices for table id' error in siddhi?

Tags: siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I'm trying to store events that meets some filters into a elastic index but when i set the store table it says that it can't create the index for that table.

I've test this in the 4.3.0 and the 4.4.0 versions of the product and none of them have worked.

```
@store(type = 'elasticsearch', host = 'elastic.local', port = '9200', index.name = '{{name}}_alertas') 
define table alertas (timestamp long, name string, ipsrc string, ipdst string, evento string, tipoAmenaza string, eventCategory string, severity string);


@info(name = 'query-all-events-elastic')
from LogStream[evento == "THREAT" and tipoAmenaza == "spyware" and eventCategory != "unknown" and (severity == "critical" or severity == "high" or severity == "medium")] 
select eventTimestamp() as timestamp, name, ipsrc, ipdst, evento, tipoAmenaza, eventCategory, severity 
insert into alertas;
```

the entire log is the next one:

```
[2019-05-31 10:51:55,394] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer} - org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.SiddhiAppCreationException: Error on 'AlertasPorCorreo' @ Line: 39. Position: 152, near '@store(type = 'elasticsearch', host = '172.20.240.250', port = '9200', index.name = '{{name}}_alertas')
define table alertas (timestamp long, name string, ipsrc string, ipdst string, evento string, tipoAmenaza string, eventCategory string, severity string)'. Error while creating indices for table id : 'alertas org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.exception.SiddhiAppDeploymentException: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.SiddhiAppCreationException: Error on 'AlertasPorCorreo' @ Line: 39. Position: 152, near '@store(type = 'elasticsearch', host = '172.20.240.250', port = '9200', index.name = '{{name}}_alertas')
define table alertas (timestamp long, name string, ipsrc string, ipdst string, evento string, tipoAmenaza string, eventCategory string, severity string)'. Error while creating indices for table id : 'alertas
        at org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer.deploySiddhiQLFile(StreamProcessorDeployer.java:105)
        at org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer.deploy(StreamProcessorDeployer.java:306)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.lambda$deployArtifacts$0(DeploymentEngine.java:291)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.deployArtifacts(DeploymentEngine.java:282)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.RepositoryScanner.sweep(RepositoryScanner.java:112)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.RepositoryScanner.scan(RepositoryScanner.java:68)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.start(DeploymentEngine.java:121)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngineListenerComponent.onAllRequiredCapabilitiesAvailable(DeploymentEngineListenerComponent.java:216)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.lambda$notifySatisfiableComponents$7(StartupComponentManager.java:266)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.notifySatisfiableComponents(StartupComponentManager.java:252)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver$1.run(StartupOrderResolver.java:204)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.SiddhiAppCreationException: Error on 'AlertasPorCorreo' @ Line: 39. Position: 152, near '@store(type = 'elasticsearch', host = '172.20.240.250', port = '9200', index.name = '{{name}}_alertas')
define table alertas (timestamp long, name string, ipsrc string, ipdst string, evento string, tipoAmenaza string, eventCategory string, severity string)'. Error while creating indices for table id : 'alertas
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.ExceptionUtil.populateQueryContext(ExceptionUtil.java:43)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SiddhiAppParser.defineTableDefinitions(SiddhiAppParser.java:322)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SiddhiAppParser.parse(SiddhiAppParser.java:224)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:65)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:74)
        at org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorService.deploySiddhiApp(StreamProcessorService.java:100)
        at org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer.deploySiddhiQLFile(StreamProcessorDeployer.java:93)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.wso2.extension.siddhi.store.elasticsearch.exceptions.ElasticsearchEventTableException: Error while creating indices for table id : 'alertas
        at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.store.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchEventTable.init(ElasticsearchEventTable.java:317)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.table.record.AbstractRecordTable.init(AbstractRecordTable.java:69)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.table.Table.initTable(Table.java:121)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.helper.DefinitionParserHelper.addTable(DefinitionParserHelper.java:210)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.SiddhiAppRuntimeBuilder.defineTable(SiddhiAppRuntimeBuilder.java:125)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SiddhiAppParser.defineTableDefinitions(SiddhiAppParser.java:320)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:171)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:145)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:348)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:192)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[2019-05-31 10:51:55,401]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.CarbonStartupHandler} - WSO2 Stream Processor started in 23,177 sec
```

Comment: Can you share the log entries with the complete stack trace while you trying to start the Siddhi application?

Comment: I added the log to de question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be two errors in the provided log. 
1. When you try to start the application it threw the first exception which is due to a syntax issue.
2. The second exception is caused due to a connection refuse from the ElasticSearch server.

Can you check whether you have access to the ElasticSearch server with the configs used under @store.

Comment: i tried conecting to the elasticsearch with that configuration and i can connect to it so that doesn't seem to be the problem, could it be because of the version of the ElasticSearch that it doesn't have the X-pack?

Comment: i got it to work using the elasticsearch.member.list attribute, it seems that using the host always calls for the localhost